# how to delete translations for I18n with RedisStore backend in Rails?

Tags: redis, rails-i18n

I've got a whole bunch of i18n translations in redis.  The way they're getting entered is:

```
store_translations(locale, { 'my-namespace' => data }, options)
```

...

When I look at redis.keys, I see a whole bunch of things like:

'en.my-namespace.foo', 'en.my-namespace.foo.bar', 'en.my-namespace.foo.bar.baz', etc.

So.. If I do:

```
redis.del('en.my-namespace.foo')
redis.del('en.my-namespace.foo.bar')
redis.del('en.my-namespace.foo.baz')
```

I call redis.keys, and I see all the keys are gone...  good.

Yet if I do:

```
redis_store.translate(locale, 'my-namespace', :scope => nil)
```

I see all the translations (keys and their values) are still there!  Where are these being stored?  How can this be happening if all the keys are gone?

Comment: Can you step inside the `translate` method ? Perhaps it caches the values. Or, the info is present in other keys.